# How to reference env directories of openshift in a python script?

Tags: python, cron, openshift

OpenShift has these default dir's:

```
# $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP']  - IP Address assigned to the application
# $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME']  - Application name
# $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DIR']   - Application dir
# $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR']  - For persistent storage (between pushes)
# $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR']   - Temp storage (unmodified files deleted after 10 days)
```

How do reference them in a python script? 
Example script "created a log file in log directory and log in data directory?

```
from time import strftime

now= strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
fn  = "${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/test.log"
fn2 = "${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/test.log"
#fn  = "test.txt"

input = "appended text " + now + " \n"

with open(fn, "ab")  as f: 
       f.write(input)
with open(fn2, "ab") as f: 
       f.write(input)
```

Can these script be used with cron?

**EDIT the BASH File:**

```
#! /bin/bash

#date >> ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/new.log
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python-2.6/virtenv/bin/activate
python file.py
date >> ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/new2data.log
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP")
```

should work.

So with your example, modify to:-

```
import os
OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR = os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR") 
fn  = os.path.join(OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR, "test.log")
```

And, yes, you can call this python script with a cron by referencing your bash script if you want... Like this for example:-

```
 #!/bin/bash
 date >> ${OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR}/status.log
 chmod +x status
 cd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/wsgi/crawler
 nohup python file.py 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Can this file.py be in the cron directories or does this file.py have to be referenced in file.sh script?

Comment: You can directly call this script in your cron by referring to it as `python /path/to/your/file.py` in your crontab.  Cron will use the python program to execute this script as expected.

Comment: OpenShift doesnt have crontab. I have file.py in cron/minutely.

Comment: Executing your python script and relinquishing control after that so there's no `stdout` and the program runs in the background. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: Are you able to execute `python file.py` in your openshift server after ssh-ing in your bash environment?

Comment: Anywhere that you decide to locate it in. Wherever you decide to place your file.py, make sure that the script calls it from its absolute path.  like this `python /path/to/whereever/file.py`

Comment: Locally its in same directory with the bash script, Found repo/data/cron/minutely   The dir is empty...

Comment: I am not sure how openshift's cron mechanism works but I suppose you are supposed to place your bash scripts in that directory in order for the script to run? In any case, make sure you point to your python file's path correct.

Answer (score 2):

Those variables OPENSHIFT_* are provided as environment variables on OpenShift -- so the $_ENV["OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR"] is an example to get the value inside a php script.

In python, the equivalent would just be os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR"). 
Made edits to Calvin's post above and submitted 'em.

Re: the question of where file.py exists -- use os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR") as the base directory where all your code would be located on the gear where you app is running. 
So if your file is located in .openshift/misc/file.py -- then just use:

```
os.path.join(os.getenv("OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"), ".openshift", "misc", "file.py")
```

to get the full path.

Or in bash, the equivalent would be:

```
$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/.openshift/misc/file.py
```

HTH

Comment: Once you clarified that your env variables in your question above are php variables, the syntax changes below. Updated my answer.